# yocto beaglebone black pru configuration

Tags: yocto

i'm trying to get the PRU enabled in yocto (morty) for the beaglebone black, however i get the following error:

***ERROR: pru-icss was skipped: incompatible with machine beaglebone (not in COMPATIBLE_MACHINE)***

these are my layers:

`BBLAYERS ?= " \/home/auke/workspace/yocto/poky/meta \
  /home/auke/workspace/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/auke/workspace/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-bbb  \
  /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-qt5  \
  /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking  \
  /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe  \
  /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python  \
  /home/auke/workspace/yocto/layers/meta-ti  \
  "`

which are all in the morty branch.
The package depends on the following

```
recipes-bsp/pru/pru-icss_git.bb:COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "ti33x|ti43x|omap-a15|k2g"
```

My question is, how can i configure the ***MACHINE ?= "beaglebone"*** variable in my local.conf such that it includes the ti33x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid having both `meta-yocto-bsp` and `meta-ti` in your `bblayers.conf`!

Both of these two layers are BSP-layers *that defines* a `beaglebone` machine.

In `meta-ti`, the `beaglebone` machine is part of `ti33x`, however, the `meta-yocto-bsp` version of `beaglebone` doesn't know anything of `ti33x` (which in turn is defined in `meta-ti`).

Thus, you `bblayers.conf` mixes those two machines with an identical name.  The solution for you is to remove `meta-yocto-bsp`, as you want eg `pru`-stuff from `meta-ti`.

Comment: thank you. I also had to remove meta-bbb for the obvious reasons.